# How to find, import and use a specific font?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to find and import a font face called `neontubes`, failing that, a font face called `freestyle script`. As I understand, I need an `src` which I would place in my style.css and then select it through style `.div {font-family: foobar;}` 
So where are the list of not just these two font types but all of them with an `src`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save and download your required font files in a folder.
In your style sheet write the following,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "foobar";
  src: url("specify the location of your font files") format("specify font format");
}

.div {font-family: foobar};
```

**To use google fonts there are two ways in which you can do that**

**linking the url in html and mentioning the font-family in your css file.**

```
link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=*family-name*" rel="stylesheet"
```

and mention the following in your css file

```
font-family: *family-name-given-in-the-link*;
```

**second way is to give the url directly in your css file**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family= *family-name*');
```

mention the following in the same css file

```
font-family: *family-name-given-in-the-link*;
```

Comment: Thanks. So i would have to do two stages. 1. `@font-face {
  font-family: "foobar";
  src: url("specify the location of your font files") format("specify font format");
}

.div {font-family: foobar};` 2. `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family= *family-name*');` or `link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=*family-name*" rel="stylesheet"` in my `<head>

Comment: Yes, In any of the two ways you can do the same. if you want to use custom downloaded font-files use font-face or if you want google fonts use the other last two methods(html link or importing font link in css). Hope that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, i still don't get it. I put `@import url ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacific')`  in my css box and i just rejects it with red lines as though it's not correct. To reiterate, all i need to do is put `@import url ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacific')` in my css box amd then use`.div {font-family....}`?

Comment: You have mentioned "Pacific" but I have found it's "Pacifico" in https://fonts.google.com/?query=pacific&selection.family=Pacifico. To reiterate put the @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico'); at the beginning of your css file and also write .div {font-family: 'Pacifico' , cursive};

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to find fonts and their way to be insert in a page, I'd suggest you to look at [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

To use fonts with links, you could simple link the font from Google on your `<head>` section :

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Then on your CSS you'd just pretty much link the font on your element :

```
YourClassHere {
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}
```

If you want to make it straight into the CSS code, you can use the attribute `@import`, it'll look pretty muc like this :

```
YourClassHere {
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine');
    font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}
```

More info about how to use fonts from Google : 
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

**NOTE** :. If you want to download the font and use it straight on your server/computer for offline codign, you should use another property on CSS.

Then, after downloading the font you want, add it on your project folder and your CSS code will have a look like this :

- First you will have to specify the font using the `@font-face`
  attribute :
  @font-face {
    font-family: NameYourFontHere;
    src: url(TheNameOfTheFontYouDownloadedHere.woff); //Don't forget to specify the type of your font at the end
  }
- Then you can use it after specifying the font in the way above :

  div {
    font-family: NameYourFontHere;
  }

Reference for `@font-face` rule :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Reference for `@import` rule :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. So if I put <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"> in my <head> then that will allow me to use `Tangerine` as `{font-family: tangerine;}` and won't just change all my fonts to `Tangerine`? Also, what's all this `scr` stuff and is that a way of linking direct through css whilst avoiding html references?

Comment: Yes, you can call the `font-type` on css for the classes or links or any element in the website you want, just make sure you want to link the element class when adding the font.

I.e : a {font-family: Tangerine;} will make all your links with this font, if you want just a specific link, add a class name to the link and do the same using the class you just created.

The `src` attribute is used when you have downloaded the font on your  server/computer and want to load it to the page :

I.e : @font-face {
           font-family: myFirstFont;
           src: url(sansation_light.woff);
 }

Comment: Done, edited it in a way that will be as clear as possible